# VBA code example to apply style to a document from another document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need some help in creating macros. After I get the style name from a Word document i don`t know how to apply it in other word document.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the straight-forward way?

```
Dim MyStyle As Style

Set MyStyle = MyDocument.Styles("MyStyle")
YourDocument.Paragraphs(1).Style = MyStyle
```

Comment: Yes, I have used it, but I don`t know how to apply it for a selection of paragraphs. I have tried with  Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(myStyle) where myStyle is a style from a dict with different styles.

Comment: `Selection.Range.Style = myStyle` would apply the style to all of the current Selection.

Comment: In my trials the above didn't work as expected. The new style over-wrote the existing. To have both the existing and the new you may have to add the style with `YourDocument.Styles.Add "MyStyle", wdStyleType` and then assign the existing MyStyle to the new "MyStyle" style. You may like to look into "Automatically update document styles" as an alternative not requiring code.

Comment: I've tried                                                                                   `styleName = VBA.InputBox("New Style Name")
  
  'CommandBars("Styles").Visible = False
  ActiveDocument.Styles.Add Name:=styleName, Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph
  ActiveDocument.Styles(styleName).AutomaticallyUpdate = True
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles(styleName).font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    End With`

Comment: @Variatus "Automatically update document styles" only updates the styles in the document to match the styles in the attached template and is somewhat selective in what it updates.

Comment: @m4o_tim I'm aware of that. But if the OP has one particular style he needs to carry, he might add it to a template which can be hitched to the document where he wants it.

Comment: @nunu1124 I can see that the moment of truth has come for you. Please stop trying anything. Instead apply the code I provided in a sensible manner. If you can't do that, write what you want to do, one precise thought in one line, like code, and we will get your thoughts translated. BTW, your statement that "I need some help" seems to have been an understatement of Trumponian proportions. I would consider it fair if you would do a little research before you continue this conversation, just to make sure that you know what a "style" is to MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply a style from another document if it exists and has the same settings in the document where you want to apply it.

To copy the style from Document A to Document B you will need to use the Organizer. [This article](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/how-to-import-styles-from-other-documents-in-word-2013/) will show you how to do that through the interface. If you need to do that using code then [see here for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835492.aspx).